# How to resolve Android get-app-links Returns State 1024?

Tags: java, android, android-deep-link

I can't get deep links to work on Android 13, I've followed every tutorial out there and can't get the app to simply start after entering the website.

I used the command in the android studio terminal:

```
adb shell pm get-app-links com.where44444.cleanbook
```

and it returns

```
  com.where44444.cleanbook:
    ID: 0892ecd5-a93b-4064-bb2c-5d6cae6e7ac6
    Signatures: [9D:F7:97:FE:92:94:1A:67:96:80:D4:07:84:F8:42:8E:96:50:2B:C2:2D:CC:19:AD:0F:CC:F1:A4:E0:72:39:BE]
    Domain verification state:
      cleanassistant.net: 1024
      www.cleanassistant.net: 1024
```

The documentation says

> Error code of 1024 or greater
>
> > Custom error code that's specific to the device's verifier.

> > Double-check that you have established a network connection, and invoke the domain verification process again.

I am indeed connected to the internet both on laptop and phone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

I think the issue is you need to include that signature into your `assetlinks.json`. I see your file here:

https://cleanassistant.net/.well-known/assetlinks.json

It does *not* have the signature in your output: `9D:F7:97:FE:92:94:1A:67:96:80:D4:07:84:F8:42:8E:96:50:2B:C2:2D:CC:19:AD:0F:CC:F1:A4:E0:72:39:BE`

Are doing a local build that is not signed by the Google Play store? We had the same problem, and the issue was that our `assetlinks.json` only included the Google Play certificate fingerprint, not the certificate fingerprint used when creating local builds (whether `.aab` or `.apk`). Once we added the local fingerprint to `assetlinks.json`, the app link successfully `verified`. Without that, we kept getting the `1024` error.

Your `assetlinks.json` is otherwise valid, as you can verify here:

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://cleanassistant.net&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

Comment: It is means must upload `.apk` or `.aab` to playstore to make the domain verification verified ?

Answer (score 11):

The solution that worked for me was replacing my SHA256 fingerprint in my assetlinks.json with the Signature that's returned from

```
adb shell pm get-app-links com.package.name
```

Most of the documentation suggests using the fingerprint that's returned from your signing key:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore release-key.keystore -alias <alias> -storepass <password> -keypass <password>
```

But that didn't work for me because Google Play now seems to be signing my app even though when I generate the .aab in Android Studio, the local key is used. The inner workings of that I don't fully understand but I was getting the `1024` error for weeks.

Steps:

1. Run `adb shell pm get-app-links com.package.name`
2. That will return something like:

```
ID: a07e3734-cdbd-4389-946c-b9ebda8c3892
    Signatures: [00: .... the actual fingerprint ..... 00]
    Domain verification state:
      app.revillager.com: 1024
```

3. Take that signature and paste that into your assetlinks.json:

```
{
 ...
 "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "00: .... the actual fingerprint ..... 00"
      ]
 ...
}
```

4. Push that file to your hosting service.
5. Run the re-verify command, checking the status after 10 seconds (may have to do this multiple times):

```
adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify com.package.name
adb shell pm get-app-links com.package.name
```

6. Once you see `Domain verification state: com.package.name: verified`, test this is working by using:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://deeplinksite.com"
```

And that should launch the app on your device instead of in chrome.

Answer (score 4):

In our case we had indeed a missing signature in the `assetlinks.json`.

**BUT**, the file was agressively cached. Which caused the app not to re-verify once we fixed it.

After we stopped setting a cache header for the file and a force re-verify via

`adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify com.example`

We could indeed get it to work.

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes for it to reset/clear cache (using firebase hosting).

Answer (score 2):

Helpful links to understand the all thing and debug these issues :

- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks
- https://zarah.dev/2022/02/08/android12-deeplinks.html
- https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/5-gotchas-of-androids-deep-link-implementation-8d6499051274

Also, you can monitor this in Google Play Console, in the Deep links menu. You can get some hints there.

In my case, the issue was geofencing enable to Europe for my domain, making it impossible for Google to verify links (because they seems to do it from USA), so I needed to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the suggestions work for you, and you have your phone or emulator connected to a proxy or VPN, The automatic verification won't work, resulting in a 1024 verification code.

You need to reinstall the app whilst not in the proxy or VPN so that the automatic verification is generated again OR you can run this command in Android Studio Terminal:

```
adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify [your app package name]
```

This fix the problem for me!