# Android App Link opens browser instead of App and supported web link is disabled in app info

Tags: android, android-12, android-deep-link, android-13, android-app-links

For Android 12 and 13, We recently enabled App link for deep link navigation. We created the assetlinks.json as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks)

Code from android manifest:

```
       <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:host="host-name" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/path"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" />

            </intent-filter>
```

But unfortunately, everytime the deeplink to the app is accessed, the link opens in chrome instead of re-directing to the app. Also in the app info, our domain is always disabled [app-info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGcvc.png)

When I run this command  `adb shell pm get-app-links <package_name>`
I get this,

```
ID: <id>
Signatures: [*]
Domain verification state:
<my_domain>: 1024
```

I am unable to figure out why it returns 1024. In google play console, this is the content of the assetLinks.json

```
{"relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],"target":{"namespace":"android_app","package_name":"<package-name>","sha256_cert_fingerprints":["<finger_print>"]}}]
```

I have tried all the steps in these pages

[1024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73737278/how-to-resolve-android-get-app-links-returns-state-1024)
[SHA-256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71664435/app-link-not-opening-in-android-12-by-default-possible-sha256-issue/71676088#71676088)

But none of the fixes mentioned here has worked for me. This is creating a huge production incident.

In this [post](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/5-gotchas-of-androids-deep-link-implementation-8d6499051274), they are saying the disabling is expected. But I have checked other apps like LinkedIn and there is no switch button beside the supported links.

I have verified the my local SHA-256 and google play app signing SHA-256 are the same. Still the domain appears disabled. Manually asking the user to enable doesnt seem like a good user experience. How can we enable this automatically?

Comment: Can you tell me which browser you are using.
If its other than chrome. you need to enable the app linking toggle in firefox and in samsung internet.
also check your app, settings and check the supported links, weather the link verification process was successful. if you see no urls there, then u have a problem , it that supported links toggle is OFF , then you have a problem and if you are using browser other than chrome, that is a problem but can be partially fixed

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: then there should be no problem with chrome. unless your app link sync failed open link in app is disabled.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm having same issue. It works fine on Samsung Internet but doesn't work while using Chrome

Comment: @Balanced02 : Unfortunately, the https way of deeplink still has issues with verification. So I decided to go with custom scheme for deeplink which works well. I am using something like myapp://

Comment: @KsiAndroid thanks for the response. I'm still trying to figure this out though. I'll update you if I'm able to resolve it.

Cheers!